# Flutter bottom sheet corner radius

Tags: dart, material-design, flutter, bottom-sheet

I am writing an app that needs to have a bottomsheet with corner radius. Something like you can see in the Google Task app.

Here is the code I have

```
showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (builder) {
          return new Container(
            height: 350.0,
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: new Container(
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: const Radius.circular(10.0), topRight: const Radius.circular(10.0))),
                child: new Center(
                  child: new Text("This is a modal sheet"),
                )),
          );
        });
```

Is still shows the sheet without the border radius.
[image]

Okay, I found a reason. It is indeed displaying the rounded corner but the background of the Container is staying white due to Scaffold background color. 
Now the question is how do I override the Scaffold background color.

Answer (score 9):

For those who still trying to resolve this:

for some reasons `Colors.transparent` does not work, so all you need to do is change color to : `Color(0xFF737373)`

```
showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (builder) {
          return new Container(
            height: 350.0,
            color: Color(0xFF737373),
            child: new Container(
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: const Radius.circular(10.0), topRight: const Radius.circular(10.0))),
                child: new Center(
                  child: new Text("This is a modal sheet"),
                )),
          );
        });
```

Comment: its for those who do not want to use `ThemeData`

Answer (score 5):

```
  _settingModalBottomSheet(context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext bc){
        return Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(ScreenUtil().setWidth(16)),
              topRight: Radius.circular(ScreenUtil().setWidth(16))
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

It looks like this:
[result_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0aUT.png)

After add below code in `main.dart`:

```
return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    canvasColor: Colors.transparent
  ),
);
```

It looks like this:
[result_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/he3jE.jpg)

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I answered.

Answer (score 5):

use shape property inside show showModalBottomSheet and give it RoundedRectangleBorder.

```
showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        shape : RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius : BorderRadius.circular(20)
        ),
        builder: (builder) {
          return new Container(
            height: 350.0,
            color: Color(0xFF737373),
            child: new Container(
                child: new Center(
                  child: new Text("This is a modal sheet"),
                )),
          );
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this code, it's working perfectly for me!

```
shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0))
```

Here is the full code.

```
showModalBottomSheet(
       shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
       ),
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext bc) {
          return StatefulBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter state) {
            return SingleChildScrollView(
                child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: Container(
                        margin:
                            EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10),
                        child: Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: Container()))));
          });
        });
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so changing the `canvasColor` in my app's main theme to `Colors.transparent` worked.

Answer (score 0):

USE ClipRRect Widget like below.

```
showMaterialModalBottomSheet(
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                context: context,
                builder: (context, scrollController) =>
                    ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                      child: Container(
                        height:
                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                            0.95,
                        child: whateverChild();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use shape property.

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(40),
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(40),
                  ),
    ),
    builder: (builder) {
      return new Container(
        height: 350.0,
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: YourWidget(),
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also check the widgets on the sheet.
Even if the border is applied, it seems that other widgets fill the space and are not applied.
Use padding, etc. to secure the upper space of the seat.

Answer (score 0):

**main_screen file:**

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: Column(
          children: [
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                    _scaffoldKey.currentState!
                        .showBottomSheet(
                    (context) => const AddItemBottomSheet(),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    );
                },
                child: Column(children: [
                    const Icon(
                    Icons.add_circle_outline_rounded,
                    size: 32,
                    ),
                    Text(
                    'Add Item',
                    ),
                ]),
                ),
          ]
      )
  );
}
```

**add_item_bottom_sheet.dart**

```
class AddItemBottomSheet extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddItemBottomSheet({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AddItemBottomSheet> createState() => _AddItemBottomSheetState();
}

class _AddItemBottomSheetState extends State<AddItemBottomSheet> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white,
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
            blurRadius: 60.0,
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
            spreadRadius: 50,
            offset: const Offset(0.0, -10.0)),
       ],
      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
        topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
      ),
     ),
     child: SingleChildScrollView(
     child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
          
              //Your UI items on BottomSheet

          ],
        ),
     ),
    ),
  );
 }
}
```

[image: demo_preview]

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue when I was using the `modal_bottom_sheet` library. but after I set the backgroundColor to transparent... it worked like magic

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, // Add this line of Code

    builder: (builder) {
      return new Container(
        height: 350.0,
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: new Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: const Radius.circular(10.0), topRight: const Radius.circular(10.0))),
            child: new Center(
              child: new Text("This is a modal sheet"),
            )),
      );
    });
```